# Подмена файлов на сервере

Tags: php, javascript, apache

Задался вопросом как реализовать незаметную подмену файлов на сервере что бы это не было заметно пользователю? Сразу оговорюсь, что речь идет о сайте полностью на Ajax, т.е. страницы подгружаются.

Допустим нашел я в одном файле баг, и мне надо быстро его подправить и выкатить на основной сайт, тут как я понимаю работает простой принцип замены файлов через консоль (что бы замена была быстрой, хотя все же остается шанс что пользователь попадет на эти доли секунды и файл загрузится частично), но вот если мне надо поправить .js или обновить дизайн - в первом случае подойдет подмена через консоль, во втором случае наверное надо полностью менять директорию с html файлами, например была папка "../main/" и поменял в настройках на "../new/", но в обоих случаях требуется перезагрузка станицы, тут получается постоянно придется .js скрипту мониторить нет ли команды на перезагрузку страницы, и при ее получении делать перезагрузку.

Не хотелось бы городить огород, по этому хотел узнать, в правильную сторону ли я смотрю, или есть более простые способы?

Comment: Настолько супер хайлоад проект? Ставьте заглушку на время обновления "сайт на обслуживании". И паранойу как рукой снимет. :)

Comment: Да, настолько. Ставить заглушку ради пары файлов и пары секунд не вариант)

Comment: @Denis Но в зависимости от сайта, проекта это может быть критичным. Может у вас сайт где человек билет на самолет заказывает. Страница заказа или корзины. А вы в это время возьмете и измените файл. У юзера все накроется медным тазом, а не дай боже вообще деньги спишутся просто так.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Такие варианты само собой учитываются. Интересен сам факт как это реализовано на большинстве крупных сайтов. Насколько я знаю, тот же ВК все делает без заглушек, и ни каких проблем это не вызывает. Тут конечно вопрос кривости рук, надо делать так что бы новые файлы на бекэнде были совместимы со старыми файлами на фронт энде, но бывают случаи когда надо сделать правку бекенд+фронтэнд, правка может быть мелкая, но критичная, и в таком случае поможет только принудительная перезагрузка, ну или по крайне мере вывод пользователю сообщение о том что требуется перезагрузка.

Comment: @Denis ВК обновляет не сразу, а только при следующем ajax-запросе. Ну а в нём вернуть даты изменения файлов не должно быть проблемой. При этом иногда после такого запроса страница обновляется-таки принудительно

Answer (score 2):

Я правильно вас понял, вы хотите организовать схему:

1. Клиент загрузил страницу
2. Вы на странице нашли баг
3. Исправили файл на сервере
4. У клиента    должна перезагрузить страничка, с обновленным  файлом

Используйте *WebSocket*.
Каждый клиент подключается к серверу, который при каких либо изменениях файла отправляет всем подключенным команду - перезагрузить страничку

Есть хорошая библиотека для этого [socket.io](http://socket.io/) ( для *socket-сервера* нужен *Node.js*, можете запустить его параллельно с вашим обычным сервером )

Когда изменяете файл отправляете команду *nodejs-серверу* ( либо на *nodejs-сервере* прописать какой-нибудь *watcher* )

Так сможете организовать принудительный update)

---

**P.S.**
Меня бы это, как посетителя сайта, не совсем бы устроило ( особенно, если вы часто будите править ), когда моя страничка сама по себе перезагружается. 
Я бы подумал, что эт вирус какой-то:D

**UPD**
На счет реализации в голову пришла неплохая идея: *вместо перезагрузки, просто покажите банер/попап/строку/уведомление, что на сайте произошли изменения, необходимо перезагрузить страничку.*

- Так вы снимите с себя ответственность за какие-либо баги на стороне
  клиента ( вы его предупредили о том, что нужно перезагрузить
  страничку, пусть все сохраняет на текущий момент и перезагружается
  )
- Более мягкий *update*.

Подводные камни тоже есть, но их решение уже вопрос выбранной конечной технологии и способа решений.

Comment: Принудительная перезагрузка конечно же имеется в виду больше про смену дизайна и исправления каких либо критических багов)